# Access a value in an array within a private object in Twig

Tags: arrays, object, twig

I want to get hold of the value of DashboardCalc, which lies in the following array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(MatrixSubHeadline)#27226 (4) {
    ["schemaHeadline":"MatrixSubHeadline":private]=>
    object(common_db_schemacontent)#28107 (12) {
      ["viewhelp":"common_db_schemacontent":private]=>
      NULL
      ["unsavedTranslations"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["objectLangCode":"common_translation_translateobject":private]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["transUseFallback":"common_translation_translateobject":private]=>
      bool(true)
      ["classData":protected]=>
      array(15) {
        ["SchemaContentID"]=>
        string(5) "15611"
        ["SchemaID"]=>
        string(3) "132"
        ["IndexNo"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["PageNo"]=>
        string(1) "7"
        ["ContentType"]=>
        string(8) "headline"
        ["QuestionID"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["HeadlineContentID"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["ImagePath"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["ThumbPath"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Text"]=>
        string(21) "Generelle kommentarer"
        ["ContentSettings"]=>
        string(2) "[]"
        ["CreatedUserID"]=>
        string(2) "15"
        ["CreatedTime"]=>
        string(19) "2021-11-11 12:36:00"
        ["UpdatedUserID"]=>
        string(2) "15"
        ["UpdatedTime"]=>
        string(19) "2021-12-17 15:35:00"
      }
      ["classChanges":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["tableName":protected]=>
      string(13) "schemacontent"
      ["primaryIDName":protected]=>
      string(15) "SchemaContentID"
      ["cacheEnabled":protected]=>
      bool(true)
      ["accountTable":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["extraData":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["saveError":"common_library_dbbase":private]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    ["questionList":"MatrixSubHeadline":private]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(MatrixQuestion)#27225 (4) {
        ["content":"MatrixQuestion":private]=>
        object(common_db_schemacontent)#28106 (12) {
          ["viewhelp":"common_db_schemacontent":private]=>
          NULL
          ["unsavedTranslations"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["objectLangCode":"common_translation_translateobject":private]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["transUseFallback":"common_translation_translateobject":private]=>
          bool(true)
          ["classData":protected]=>
          array(15) {
            ["SchemaContentID"]=>
            string(5) "15612"
            ["SchemaID"]=>
            string(3) "132"
            ["IndexNo"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["PageNo"]=>
            string(1) "7"
            ["ContentType"]=>
            string(8) "question"
            ["QuestionID"]=>
            string(3) "923"
            ["HeadlineContentID"]=>
            string(5) "15611"
            ["ImagePath"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["ThumbPath"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["Text"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["ContentSettings"]=>
            string(21) "{"criteriaenabled":0}"
            ["CreatedUserID"]=>
            string(2) "15"
            ["CreatedTime"]=>
            string(19) "2021-11-11 12:36:00"
            ["UpdatedUserID"]=>
            string(2) "15"
            ["UpdatedTime"]=>
            string(19) "2021-12-17 15:35:00"
          }
          ["classChanges":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["tableName":protected]=>
          string(13) "schemacontent"
          ["primaryIDName":protected]=>
          string(15) "SchemaContentID"
          ["cacheEnabled":protected]=>
          bool(true)
          ["accountTable":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["extraData":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["saveError":"common_library_dbbase":private]=>
          bool(false)
        }
        ["question":"MatrixQuestion":private]=>
        object(common_db_question)#27289 (13) {
          ["schemaUsage":"common_db_question":private]=>
          NULL
          ["viewHelper":"common_db_question":private]=>
          NULL
          ["unsavedTranslations"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["objectLangCode":"common_translation_translateobject":private]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["transUseFallback":"common_translation_translateobject":private]=>
          bool(true)
          ["classData":protected]=>
          array(23) {
            ["QuestionID"]=>
            string(3) "923"
            ["OwnerAccountID"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["Question"]=>
            string(21) "Generelle kommentarer"
            ["QuestionType"]=>
            string(1) "5"
            ["Answers"]=>
            string(178) "{"answers":null,"groupanswers":[{"count":"1","text":"Ja, jeg vil gerne tilf\u00f8je en generel kommentar","index":"0"}],"questions":["Har du andre kommentarer til din trivsel?"]}"
            ["SubText"]=>
            string(59) "(Skriv dine kommentarer ved at trykke på kommentar-ikonet)"
            ["AllowOther"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["MixAnswers"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["MustAnswer"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["MinAnswers"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["MaxAnswers"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["Columns"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["OtherText"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["CreatedUserID"]=>
            string(2) "15"
            ["CreatedTime"]=>
            string(19) "2021-11-11 12:36:00"
            ["UpdatedUserID"]=>
            string(2) "15"
            ["UpdatedTime"]=>
            string(19) "2021-11-11 12:44:00"
            ["DashboardShow"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["DashboardCalc"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["QuestionTags"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["UseComment"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["IsPublic"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["StdAnswer"]=>
            string(1) "0"
          }
          ["classChanges":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["tableName":protected]=>
          string(8) "question"
          ["primaryIDName":protected]=>
          string(10) "QuestionID"
          ["cacheEnabled":protected]=>
          bool(true)
          ["accountTable":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["extraData":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["saveError":"common_library_dbbase":private]=>
          bool(false)
        }
        ["text":"MatrixQuestion":private]=>
        string(41) "Har du andre kommentarer til din trivsel?"
        ["index":"MatrixQuestion":private]=>
        int(0)
      }
    }
    ["questionMap":"MatrixSubHeadline":private]=>
    array(1) {
      [15612]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(0)
      }
    }
    ["useComments":"MatrixSubHeadline":private]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

Please note: the array contains a few objects, which are private. I am not sure whether private objects can be accessed or not, or if the "private" is about the name, or the content.
The data is inherited from a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can access object value by using loop iteration like this: 
I am selecting here SchemaContentID, SchemaID and IndexNo.

{% for arrayObj in Objs %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ Objs.SchemaContentID}}</li>
        <li>{{ Objs.SchemaID}}</li>
        <li>{{ Objs.IndexNo}}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nilesh. For my understanding: shouldn't that be <li>{{ arrayObj.SchemaContentID}}</li> in stead of <li>{{ Objs.SchemaContentID}}</li>. Or do I misunderstand the concept for a for loop? The array as shown in my question is called headline, I can display it by using dump(headline)

Comment: @AlbertvanHarten , you can use loop iteration to use that type of data because there are multiple records with same key mapping.

Comment: While I really appreciate your contribution, I simply do not understand how it works.
If I copy your example into my code, nothing is being displayed! Even not if I change "Objs." with "arrayObj" and "Objs" with "headline")

Comment: Please check with console or print the object and use it.

Comment: That is what I do - but I simply cannot fetch the data out of the object - that is my whole problem!
The object is called headline.
If I use "headline.name", I get the name of the item (or whatever such is called).
If I use headline|join(', '), I can see the name, and 5 arrays.
But I cannot see how to access those arrays. It simply does not work with your example, even how much I'd like to!